# Fill VIEW data based on clicked movie

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server, model-view-controller

I am making a Movie Review site (without entity framework) ( not meant to use it)

I have a stored procedure to fill the info of the movie: 
[image: Movie slider]

This code below: is how I get the movie information based on the query below

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style="background-color:white;">
                    <div class="panel-body">

                        <div style="height:400px; width:100%;">
                            <section class="center slider" style="width: 88%;">
                                @*Aqui va el poster de reviews recientes*@
                                @foreach (var poster in Model.LGetLastReviews)
                                {
                                    <div>
                                        <a href="/Review/Review/?=@poster.Id" id="tag<%=count++%" name="@poster.Id">
                                        <img class="sizecool hvr-shrink" src="@Href("~/Content/"+@poster.Path )"/>
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="subtitulo">

                                            @poster.Title
                                            @poster.Date
                                        </div> 
                                    </div>
                                }

                            </section>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here is the query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLastReviews] @Top bigint
AS
BEGIN
SELECT TOP(@Top) Movie.Id, MOVIE.title, Poster.path_image, review.comment, review.Date from review
inner join movie on review.Movie_Id = movie.Id
inner join poster on movie.Id = poster.Movie_Id
order by review.Date desc 
END
```

Now the real question is: How to fill this other view based on what the user clicked?
get the img id,name..etc and fill this view:

[image: Movie information]

class:

```
 public class GetLastReviews
    {
        public long Id  { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    }




public static List<GetLastReviews> GetLastReviews(int top)
        {
            List<GetLastReviews> lastReviewses= new List<GetLastReviews>();
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(StrConnection);
            string cmd = "GetLastReviews";
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(cmd, connection);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Top", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = top.ToString();
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                GetLastReviews getLasR = new GetLastReviews();
                getLasR.Id = long.Parse(dr["Id"].ToString());
                getLasR.Title = dr["Title"].ToString();
                getLasR.Path = dr["Path_Image"].ToString();
                getLasR.Comment = dr["Comment"].ToString();
                getLasR.Date = DateTime.Parse(dr["Date"].ToString());
                lastReviewses.Add(getLasR);
            }
            connection.Close();
            return lastReviewses;

        }
```

Comment: Do you want to open the particular movie detail in modal popup or in new page?

Comment: New page, I have a view called movie review and it should display the selected movie info

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just bind the one function on div's click event with uniqueId(MovieId or any) in like as below.

```
@foreach (var poster in Model.LGetLastReviews)
{
 <div onclick="GoToMovieDetail(@Model.MovieId)">
     <a href="/Review/Review/?=@poster.Id" id="tag<%=count++%" name="@poster.Id">
    <img class="sizecool hvr-shrink" src="@Href("~/Content/"+@poster.Path )"/>
                                        </a>
    <div class="subtitulo">
        @poster.Title
        @poster.Date
    </div> 
 </div>
}
```

Make one function in Javascript like as below.

```
function GoToMovieDetail(id)
{
  if(id != null)
  {
    var url = "@Url.Action("DisplayMovieDetailActionName", "MovieControllerName")" + "?MovieId=" + id;
    window.location.href = url;
  }
}
```

Create one Action in your Controller to get the Movie Detail as per the requested Id in parameter as below.

```
public ActionResult DisplayMovieDetail(int id)
{
   MovieModel model = new MovieModel();

   // Get the detail of moview based on requested id in action parameter.
   // Bind MovieModel object.
   // Pass thid object in your return View.
   // In view you need to just bind the model data.

   return View(model);
}
```